# Validating the way of creating a composite score using elastic net

Tags: elastic-net, composite

We have a dataset where we want to see the association of different personal/demographic characteristics and biomarkers with post-injury depression. For that, we first want to create a composite score with important biomarkers (step-1) and use it in a logistic regression of depression to show the associations in terms of adjusted odds ratios and p-values (step-2).

We are using an elastic net to select these biomarkers as the biomarkers are highly correlated. The idea is to use the $\beta$ weights obtained from this elastic net to create a composite score of selected biomarkers.

I'm confused about if I should use the personal/demographic variables in the elastic net too. Adding some of them may change the coefficients/beta weights by a good margin and possibly make the coefficients of the biomarkers more "adjusted". We want to use these personal/demographic variables along with the created composite in the (step-2) logistic regression of depression anyway, even if some of these do not get selected by the elastic net (for example, gender/premorbid depression). The selection of biomarkers and getting stable coefficients for them are the main goals in step-1. As a result, I'm planning to make the composite like: $\hat{\beta_1}*Biomarker_1 + ... + \hat{\beta_n}*Biomarker_n$.

If we only used biomarkers in the elastic net (and not the other demographic variables), I'd probably think about finding a predicted logit ($X\hat{\beta}$) which would also include $\hat{\beta_0}$ (intercept) and use that as a composite.

Could you let me know which one seems more correct to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're asking is whether you should adjust for demographic variables in your step 1, and, if so, how? Is my understanding of your question correct?

I agree with your intuition that

> Adding some of [the personal/demographic variables] may change the coefficients/beta weights by a good margin and possibly make the coefficients of the biomarkers more "adjusted"

Furthermore, I think that if this were to happen it would be a good thing. You don't want to select biomarkers the associations of which are merely surrogates for the patient/demographic variables that you plan to include in your model anyways.

I think you should try to fit a **one-step model** by applying your elastic-net type shrinkage but decreasing or even zeroing out the penalty on the patient/demographic coefficients that you definitely want included in your model. In doing so, you would only penalize the biomarker coefficients, which you are less certain about. If you are using `glmnet` in R, you can achieve this differential penalization of coefficients with the `penalty.factor` argument.

I am generally not in favor of a two-step process such as what you propose because in step 2 you are not accounting for the underlying uncertainty in your derived predictor.